# Tomcat 7 sessionid cookie disable http-only and secure

Tags: cookies, tomcat7, session-cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

I have a web application which is running on a Tomcat 7 server. The cookie with session id has by default the flags `HttpOnly` and `Secure`. I want to disable this flags for the `JSESSIONID` cookie. But it wont work. I have changed this in my `web.xml` file but it is not working.

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>20160</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>false</http-only>
        <secure>false</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

I know this is a security risk because a attacker is able to steal the cookie and hijack the session if he has found a xss vuln.

The `JSESSIONID` cookie should be send with HTTP and HTTPS and with AJAX requests.

**Edit:**

I have successfuly disabled the `HttpOnly` flag by adding the following option to the `conf/context.xml` file:

```xml
<Context useHttpOnly="false">
....
</Context>
```

Comment: Please close this question, you got the answer. Thanks.

Comment: did you find out how to disable secured?

Comment: Chrome's recent update makes this very important! https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a26e439d02baa9514b09c637bf5fa9f6790c4c3e

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [code from tomcat](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.24/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationSessionCookieConfig.java#ApplicationSessionCookieConfig.createSessionCookie%28org.apache.catalina.Context%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%29) you will find:

```
// Always set secure if the request is secure
if (scc.isSecure() || secure) {
    cookie.setSecure(true);
}
```

So trying to deactivate Secure flag on JSESSIONID cookie with `sessionCookieConfig.setSecure(false);` in a listener or `<cookie-config><secure>false</secure></cookie-config>` in the web.xml WON'T WORK as Tomcat force the secure flag to true if the request is secure (ie came from an https url or the SSL port).

A solution is to use a request filter to modify the JSESSIONID cookie on the server response immediately after the session creation.
This is my implementation (very basic):

```
public class DisableSecureCookieFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest && response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            request = new ForceUnsecureSessionCookieRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse) response);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

    public static class ForceUnsecureSessionCookieRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        HttpServletResponse response;

        public ForceUnsecureSessionCookieRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(request);
            this.response = response;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpSession getSession(boolean create) {
            if(create) {
                HttpSession session = super.getSession(create);
                updateCookie(response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie"));
                return session;
            }
            return super.getSession(create);
        }

        @Override
        public HttpSession getSession() {
            HttpSession session = super.getSession();
            if(session != null) {
                updateCookie(response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie"));
            }

            return session;
        }

        protected void updateCookie(Collection<String> cookiesAfterCreateSession) {
            if(cookiesAfterCreateSession != null && !response.isCommitted()) {
                // search if a cookie JSESSIONID Secure exists
                Optional<String> cookieJSessionId = cookiesAfterCreateSession.stream()
                                                        .filter(cookie -> cookie.startsWith("JSESSIONID") && cookie.contains("Secure"))
                                                        .findAny();
                if(cookieJSessionId.isPresent()) {
                    // remove all Set-Cookie and add the unsecure version of the JSessionId Cookie
                    response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookieJSessionId.get().replace("Secure", ""));

                    // re-add all other Cookies
                    cookiesAfterCreateSession.stream()
                            .filter(cookie -> !cookie.startsWith("JSESSIONID"))
                            .forEach(cookie -> response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and in the web.xml :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>disableSecureCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.xxxx.security.DisableSecureCookieFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>disableSecureCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Remember that enabling insecure cookies bypass an important https security!** (I had to do that for a smooth transition from http to https)

Comment: Instead of filtering on prefix and secure anywhere in the line, it's more robust to use e.g. java.net.HttpCookie.parse(str) and then use the getter methods to extract the proper parts.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find a solution in Tomcat to this but if you're using apache as a reverse proxy you can do:

```
Header edit* Set-Cookie "(JSESSIONID=.*)(; Secure)" "$1"
```

with `mod_headers` which will munge the header on the way back out to remove the secure flag. Not pretty but works if this is critical.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to George Powell's solution above for Apache, if you are on IIS, you can solve it as follows:

1. Install the IIS URL Rewrite module
2. Add the following to your web.config

```html
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="RemoveSecureJessionID">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="^(.*JSESSIONID.*)Secure;(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

This solution was from [Pete Freitag's blog](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/817.cfm)

As stated above, since the recent Chrome update (Jan 2017), this has become an issue.